# Current in \$R{_1}\$ of resistor divider with capacitor

Tags: capacitor, circuit-analysis, control-system, laplace-transform

Given the system[image: circuit] calculate the current in \$R_{1}\$, $$R_{1}=R_{2}=10k\Omega $$ and $$C=1.2\mu F$$. Well, I have two approaches.

- When the capacitor is fully charged, it will open the circuit and there will be a voltage divisor

So $$V_{R_{1}}=20_V\frac{10k\Omega}{20k\Omega}=10_V$$
and then
$$I_{R{1}}=\frac{10_V}{10k\Omega}=1mA$$

- Model the system, calculate the step response and you will have the capacitor voltage, so $$V_{C}=V_{R_2}$$ and then $$V_{R1}=V-V_{C}$$
  System model:
  $$\frac{V(t)}{R_{1}C}=\dot{V_{C}}+\frac{1}{C}(\frac{R_1+R_2}{R_1R_2})V_{C}$$
  the time constant:
  $$\tau=C(\frac{R_1R_2}{R_1+R_2})=0.006s$$
  taking the Laplace transform with the input given and aplying the values of the components
  $$1666.6\frac{1}{s}=V_{C(s)}-V_{C(0)}+166.6V_{C(s)}$$
  Grouping, calculating the partial fractions expansion and taking the inverse Laplace transform:
  $$\frac{1666.6}{s(s+166.6)}=V_{C(s)}$$ 
  $$V_{C}=\frac{10.0036}{s}+\frac{-10.0036}{s+166.6}=10.0036-10.0036e^{-166.6t}$$ with $$t\geq0$$ and when
  $$\underset{t\rightarrow\infty}{\lim V_{C}}=10.0036V$$ then (again)  $$V_{R1}=V-V_{C}$$
  $$V_{R1}=20V-10.0036V=9.9964V$$
  $$I_{R{1}}=\frac{9.9964_V}{10k\Omega}=0.00099964A$$ or $$I_{R{1}}\approx1mA$$

  I made a graphic of the response.
  OK, hope this can be reviewed and point any error or comment if this is done right! Thanks in advance.
  [image]

Comment: looks good. now repeat until you can do in your head in 10s. 63%Vin at ReqC towards I= V/Rtot

Comment: **Just by simple inspection** you can't get the voltage across the capacitor to more than half the supply voltage so there's a little calculating error in there (probably due to approximating values in the calculation). Initially the current in R1 will be 2mA ( *capacitor acting as a short circuit* )  falling exponentially to 1mA (almost) ( *capacitor acting as an open circuit* ) after about 5 time constants - assuming no initial charge on the capacitor at t=0.

Comment: Thanks to Tony and JIm; Im checking it; whoa! I didnt think this way, =)

Comment: And.... consider if you changed your V,R1,R2 circuit to its **Thevenin equivalent**  (10V, 5k) as it charged the capacitor.

Comment: It is another way; but this time uncle Thevenin doesn’t was allowed in the question. However Im doing this too. =)

Comment: Why don't you just use the impedance of the capacitor 1/sC. It is the in parallel with the resistor. It is straight forward after that.

Comment: Keep the calculations in proper fractions for as long as possible. And if you must use decimal fractions apply the usual rules for rounding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My first instinct would be to first apply Thevenin to \$V\$, \$R_1\$, and \$R_2\$ in order to reduce this to a simple series RC problem, whose solution is:

$$\begin{align*}
R_{th} &= \frac{R_1\cdot R_2}{R_1+R_2} = 5\:\textrm{k}\Omega\\
 \\
V_{th} &= V\cdot\frac{R_2}{R_1+R_2} = \frac{1}{2}\:V \\
 \\
\tau&= R_{th} \cdot C_1 = 6\:\textrm{ms}\\
 \\
V_x=V_{R_1}&=V_{th}\cdot\left(1-e^{-\cfrac{t}{\tau}}\right)=\frac{1}{2}\:V\cdot\left(1-e^{-\cfrac{t}{\tau}}\right)
\end{align*}$$

But that's not a general approach. It just works in this case.

---

Nodal analysis is way, way more general and would be, setting the bottom node arbitrarily to \$0\:\textrm{V}\$:

$$\begin{align*}
\frac{V_x}{R_1} + \frac{V_x}{R_2} + C_1\frac{\textrm{d} V_x}{\textrm{d} t}&= \frac{V}{R_1} + \frac{0\:\textrm{V}}{R_2} \\
 \\
V_x\cdot\left(\frac{1}{R_1} + \frac{1}{R_2}\right) + C_1\frac{\textrm{d} V_x}{\textrm{d} t}&= \frac{V}{R_1} \\
 \\
\frac{\textrm{d} V_x}{\textrm{d} t}+\frac{1}{C_1\frac{R_1\cdot R_2}{R_1+R_2}}V_x&= \frac{V}{R_1 C_1} \\
 \\
\frac{\textrm{d} V_x}{\textrm{d} t}+\frac{1}{C_1 R_{th}}V_x&= \frac{V_{th}}{C_1 R_{th}}
\end{align*}$$

Which is in a very familiar first-order ODE form. You can apply Laplace to that.

But just using the usual ODE solution method for first-order, gives:

$$\begin{align*}
P_t = \frac{1}{C_1 R_{th}},~~Q_t &= \frac{V_{th}}{C_1 R_{th}},~~\therefore~~ \frac{\textrm{d} V_x}{\textrm{d} t}+P_t V_x= Q_t\\
 \\
\mu &= e^{\int P_t\:\textrm{d} t} = e^{\left[\cfrac{t}{C_1 R_{th}}\right]}\\
 \\
V_x &= \frac{1}{\mu}\int \mu\: Q_t~  \:\textrm{d} t \\
 \\
 &= e^{\left[\cfrac{-t}{C_1 R_{th}}\right]}\int e^{\left[\cfrac{t}{C_1 R_{th}}\right]}\: \frac{V_{th}}{C_1 R_{th}}~  \:\textrm{d} t \\
 \\
 &= e^{\left[\cfrac{-t}{C_1 R_{th}}\right]}\cdot \left(\frac{V_{th}}{C_1 R_{th}}\right)\cdot \int e^{\left[\cfrac{t}{C_1 R_{th}}\right]}\:~  \:\textrm{d} t \\
 \\
 &= e^{\left[\cfrac{-t}{C_1 R_{th}}\right]}\cdot \left(\frac{V_{th}}{C_1 R_{th}}\right)\cdot \left(C_1 R_{th}\: e^{\left[\cfrac{t}{C_1 R_{th}}\right]}+C_0\right) \\
 \\
 &= V_{th}\:e^{\left[\cfrac{-t}{C_1 R_{th}}\right]}\cdot \left(e^{\left[\cfrac{t}{C_1 R_{th}}\right]}+C_0\right) \\
 \\
 &= V_{th}\left(1 + C_0\:e^{\left[\cfrac{-t}{C_1 R_{th}}\right]}\right)
\end{align*}$$

Using the initial condition that \$V_x\left(t=0\right) = 0\:\textrm{V}\$, this results in \$C_0=-1\$, so:

$$\begin{align*}
V_x &= V_{th}\left(1 -e^{\left[\cfrac{-t}{C_1 R_{th}}\right]}\right) = \frac{1}{2}\:V\cdot\left(1-e^{-\cfrac{t}{\tau}}\right)
\end{align*}$$

And now you can see why the Thevenin approach would be chosen first.

---

Or use Laplace applied to the ODE mentioned earlier. Using the known initial condition, you get \$Y_s = \frac{Q_t}{s^2+P_t s}\$, which solves out as \$y_t=\frac{Q_t}{P_t}\left(1-e^{-P_t t}\right)=V_{th}\left(1-e^{\frac{-t}{\tau}}\right)=\frac{1}{2} V\left(1-e^{\frac{-t}{\tau}}\right)\$.

---

Of course, knowing \$V_x\$ it is trivial to then answer your title question regarding the current in \$R_1\$ over time.

Comment: Thanks to you all, I ve learned today to think a bit different! I never though  this can be so rich.